# Discord.py 2.0 slash command integration with commands.Bot()

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

commands.Bot() currently requires a command prefix but with discord's new slash commands that is not necessary. Is there a way to get around the required command prefix?

I am currently using discord.Client so this isn't an issue. However, after some research it seems like commands.Bot() is the better option since it is an extension of discord.Client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`discord.Client()` represents a client connection that connects to Discord. This class is used to interact with the Discord WebSocket and API. and `commands.Bot()` is just an extension to allow prefix commands, you don't need it if you have slash commands.

To answer your question, no there's no "get around" because it would make no sense. `commands.Bot()` was created to allow prefix commands and if you're bypassing it, you have a normal discord.Client instance.

1. [discord.Client()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20client#discord.Client)
2. [commands.Bot()](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=commands%20bot#discord.ext.commands.Bot)